# Content appearing behind fixed header

Tags: html, header, position, fixed

I fixed the header section of a website, but the first div of the page appears behind the header; instead of starting from the end of the header.

Comment: hi adeniyi, if you could make it more precise, like including some example, it will be easy for people to understand your question...always do proper formating, while including code and some images...Thanks!

Comment: Please add the html code by editing your post.

Answer (score 15):

When you apply `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` the element is being removed from the document flow, so the elements that come after treat it as a non-existent. That's why your `div` jumps up. To fix that apply a `margin-top` that equals to your header height - http://jsfiddle.net/2xjES/

Comment: What if the header height is variable depending on content?

Comment: @AlexanderJank I'd recommend using position:sticky at that point, which will allow the other elements to automatically respect the height of the document, but will make the header stick to the top of the page when you scroll. Be sure to add a top value (top:0px for example) to let the header know when to start sticking.