# webpage's header added via php include doesnt comply to page flow

Tags: php, html, css

In my project I use headers that are included in the webpage via php's include function. Then adding the page content I noticed that the code written in the page itself isn't added after the header but behind it.
here's the sample page's code:

```
<?php
    require_once '../WebServices/functions.php';
    sessionManager();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">
        <title>DevLancer - Developer jobs for freelancers</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION["USER_ID"])) {
                require_once '../includes/header_signed-in.php';
            } else {
                require_once '../includes/header.php';
            }
        ?>
        <form class="create-roject">
            <input type="text" placeholder="project name"><br>
            <textarea></textarea>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here's the header file:

```
<header class="header-full">
    <a href="../GUI/"><img class="logo" alt="logo" src="/Media/devlancer_vertical.png"></a>
    <div class="header-content">
        <nav class="header-top">
            <ul class="left-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="PostAProject">Post A Project</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="FindWork">Find work</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="right-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('frmRegister').style.display = 'block';">Become a member</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('frmLogin').style.display = 'block';">Already a member? Log In</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <nav class="header-bottom">
            <ul class="left-nav">
                <li>
                    <a>FAQ</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Community</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>About Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="right-nav">
                <li>
                    <a class="header-contactus">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="header-social">
                    <!--add social media links here-->
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<?php
    require_once '../includes/frmLogin.php';
    require_once '../includes/frmRegister.php';
?>
```

and here's the styling of the header (scss):

```
.header-full {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    height: 128px;
    left: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.08), 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    .logo {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline;
        margin: 0px 50px;
        height:128px;
        width: 128px;
        background-color: red;
    }
    .header-content {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 229px;
        border-left: solid 1px #ececec;
        top: 0px;
        width: calc(100% - 230px);
        height: 128px;
        .header-top {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height:87px;
            border-bottom: solid 1px #ececec;
            .nav {
                top:0;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 87px;
                list-style-type: none;
                padding-left: 40px;
                li {
                    position: relative;
                    top: -32px;
                    display: inline;
                    font-family: sans-serif;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    font-weight: bold; 
                    margin-left: 20px;
                    margin-right: 20px;
                    height: 87px;
                    input[type="search"] {
                        position: relative;
                        padding: 10px;
                        border-style: solid;
                        border-color: #0fa20f;
                        border-width: 3px;
                        border-radius: 10px;
                        font-size: 16px;
                        font-family: sans-serif;
                        top:-5px;
                    }
                    img {
                        position: relative;
                        top: 0;
                        display: inline;
                        padding: 0;
                        height: 87px;
                        border-radius: 50px;
                    }
                    img:hover {
                        cursor:pointer;
                    }
                    a:link {
                        text-decoration: none;
                        color: black;
                        animation-name: green2black;
                        animation-duration: .5s;
                    }
                    a:visited {
                        text-decoration: none;
                        color: black;
                        animation-name: green2black;
                        animation-duration: .5s;
                    }
                    a:hover {
                        text-decoration: none;
                        color: #0fa20f;
                        animation-name: black2green;
                        animation-duration: .5s;
                    }
                    a:active {
                        text-decoration: none;
                        color: black;
                        animation-name: green2black;
                        animation-duration: .5s;
                    }
                }
            }
            .left-nav {
                display: inline;
                float:left;
                vertical-align: middle;
                list-style-type: none;
                margin: 0;
                    li {
                        position: relative;
                        top: 32px;
                        bottom: 32px;
                        display: inline;
                        font-family: sans-serif;
                        font-size: 20px;
                        font-weight: bold; 
                        margin-left: 20px;
                        margin-right: 20px;

                        a:link {
                            text-decoration: none;
                            color: black;
                            animation-name: green2black;
                            animation-duration: .5s;
                        }
                        a:visited {
                            text-decoration: none;
                            color: black;
                            animation-name: green2black;
                            animation-duration: .5s;
                        }
                        a:hover {
                            text-decoration: none;
                            color: #0fa20f;
                            animation-name: black2green;
                            animation-duration: .5s;
                        }
                        a:active {
                            text-decoration: none;
                            color: black;
                            animation-name: green2black;
                            animation-duration: .5s;
                        }
                    }
            }
            .right-nav {
                display: inline;
                float:right;
                padding-right: 40px;
                vertical-align: middle;
                list-style-type: none;
                margin: 0;
                    li {
                        padding: 10px;
                        border-style: solid;
                        border-color: #0fa20f;
                        border-radius: 15px;
                        position: relative;
                        top: 32px;
                        bottom: 32px;
                        display: inline;
                        font-family: sans-serif;
                        font-size: 20px;
                        font-weight: bold; 
                        margin-left: 10px;
                        margin-right: 10px;
                        animation-name: border-black2green;
                        animation-duration: .5s;

                        a:link {
                            text-decoration: none;
                            color: black;
                        }
                        a:visited {
                            text-decoration: none;
                            color: black;
                        }
                        a:hover {
                            text-decoration: none;
                            color: #0fa20f;
                        }
                        a:active {
                            text-decoration: none;
                            color: black;
                        }
                    }
                    li:hover {
                        padding: 10px;
                        border-style: solid;
                        border-color: black;
                        border-radius: 15px;
                        position: relative;
                        top: 32px;
                        bottom: 32px;
                        display: inline;
                        font-family: sans-serif;
                        font-size: 20px;
                        font-weight: bold; 
                        margin-left: 10px;
                        margin-right: 10px;
                        animation-name: border-green2black;
                        animation-duration: .5s;

                        a:link {
                            text-decoration: none;
                            color: #0fa20f;
                            animation-name: black2green;
                            animation-duration: .5s;
                        }
                        a:visited {
                            text-decoration: none;
                            color: #0fa20f;
                            animation-name: black2green;
                            animation-duration: .5s;
                        }
                        a:hover {
                            text-decoration: none;
                            color: #0fa20f;
                            animation-name: black2green;
                            animation-duration: .5s;
                        }
                        a:active {
                            text-decoration: none;
                            color: #0fa20f;
                            animation-name: black2green;
                            animation-duration: .5s;
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        .header-bottom {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 41px;
            .left-nav {
                display: inline;
                float: left;
                margin: 0;
                li {
                    top: 11px;
                    bottom: 11px;
                    position: relative;
                    display: inline;
                    font-family: sans-serif;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    margin-left: 20px;
                    margin-right: 10px;
                }
            }
            .right-nav {
                display: inline;
                float: right;
                margin: 0;
                padding-right: 40px;
                padding-left: 0;
                li {
                    top: 11px;
                    bottom: 11px;
                    position: relative;
                    display: inline;
                    font-family:sans-serif;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    margin-left: 10px;
                    margin-right: 10px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I checked everything including z-index and searched the web for similar cases. please help!

Comment: working example would make it easier to answer

Comment: how to make it working?

Comment: What is the difference between something that's 'behind' something else and something that's 'after' something else? "...the code written in the page itself isn't added after the header but behind it.". Are you talking about inline or on the next line?

Comment: @Harry Zalessky for example here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: its being hidden by the header. it appears at location (0,0) on the page instead of appearing at (0,128)

Comment: @HarryZalessky maybe at least show real live final output... I'm just trying to help you to get an answer to your question :-)

Comment: Set the header position property to relative. The fixed takes it out of the document flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the error: as the header set to fixed it is being removed from the page flow. just added "margin-top: 128px" and everything is fixed. also discovered that it's a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126482/content-appearing-behind-fixed-header) question.

Comment: If this is a duplicate it should just be closed as a dupe, not answered.